# How to authenticate myself to download data in R?

Tags: r, authentication

I want to download secured data from LendingClub (a P2P lending company, please Google it if you're interested in what they do).

The secured data can only be downloaded if you have an account. So now I have a `username` and `password`, and I check the download page to copy the file download link. Then how can I authenticate myself to download the data? I tried the following:

```
file <- 'lc1'
url <- "https://www.lendingclub.com/fileDownload.action?type=gen&file=LoanStats3a_securev1.csv.zip"
download.file(url, file)
```

But it throws warning:

```
trying URL 'https://www.lendingclub.com/fileDownload.action?type=gen&file=LoanStats3a_securev1.csv.zip'
Content type 'text/html;charset=UTF-8' length 200 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 14 Kb

Warning message:
In download.file(url, file) :
  downloaded length 14531 != reported length 200
```

And the text file downloaded is not the zip file I want, I guess it's because no authentication step is involved, because if you don't have an account you can also download the partial data and the link is different:

```
url <- "https://resources.lendingclub.com/LoanStats3a.csv.zip"
```

and previous commands would work fine. So where can I add the authentication step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use their [REST API](https://www.lendingclub.com/developers/lc-api.action) with an API key that they give you [here](https://www.lendingclub.com/developers/authentication.action).

Then you can build a URL to the resource that you're looking to download in the format you'd like it in (or a format that you can manipulate to use in your code).

You can use curl to double-check your URL:

```
$curl -v -H "Authorization: <api key>" -XGET https://api.lendingclub.com/api/investor/v1/accounts/<investor_id>/summary
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I only have a borrower account now, but I can still authenticate myself to download the secured file from browser with clicking the link. Do I have to get an investor account for the API to download it automatically in R?

Comment: As far as I know there's nothing for borrowers available via the API